# Using jsTestDriver and Jasmine in Sublime Text 2

Tags: jasmine, sublimetext, js-test-driver

Is there a way to configure Sublime Text 2 to use Jasmine and jsTestDriver when writing JavaScript?

Comment: Define "use", what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question does not state clear goal it is difficult to guess what is being asked here. Please be more professional when asking next question.

You probably want to execute tests on each JS file save.

- As far as I know there is no Sublime Text plug-in which would provide decorated output on the lines where tests fail
- However, you can run tests on background using a generic solution like http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.6.0 which monitors files for changes and runs a command when certain files change
- If you want to pipe terminal output to a Sublime tab there is https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this will be to use "Live Reload" plugin on Sublime and Firefox.

As you save the test file it auto refreshes the Spec Runner. Not the perfect setup but works.